# Retag request [enterprise-guide] -> [sas-enterprise-guide]

Tags: feature-request, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Could someone please rename [enterprise-guide](/questions/tagged/enterprise-guide) to [sas-enterprise-guide](/questions/tagged/sas-enterprise-guide) and then create a synonym relationship for [enterprise-guide](/questions/tagged/enterprise-guide)?  Enterprise Guide is a SAS development environment (it's the 4GL part of SAS, really) and should be more clearly designated as SAS Enterprise Guide.